# counting page breaks in a word doc using word interp

Tags: c#, interop

I've been searching the internet on how to get the page breaks in a word doc but to no avail. Microsoft offers little help on this topic. I'd appreciate any help in getting the number of page breaks using word interop. I'm using winform.
Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this blog on removing section and page breaks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2009/06/15/removing-page-and-section-breaks-from-a-word-document.aspx)? (Or is it not applicable since it uses XML SDK?) I'm not familiar with `Office.Interop.Word` library, but I would imagine some facsimile of `Document.Descendants` exists within.

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Yes he is not using word interop.

Comment: @FadeIMS: Just judging by [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx) I'd have a look at [`DocumentClass.Sections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.word.documentclass.sections.aspx). It appears [`Break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.break)s fall under this category which would lead me to believe you could iterate over the enumerable and remove as necessary. (Just an educated guess).

Comment: Are you looking for deliberate breaks (e.g. forced page break - that which is created when the user hits ctrl-break) or are you looking for the natural page breaks that occur when Word formats the file?  @BradChristie - I believe DocumentClass.Sections enumerates section breaks, but not page breaks within a section.

Comment: @Avi: I'm looking for those inserted by users using "Insert->Page Breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the page breaks by searching for ^012, like so:

```
            int totalPageBreaks = 0;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng;

            rng = doc.Range();
            rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);

            while (true) {
                rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
                rng.Find.Text = "^012";
                rng.Find.Forward = true;
                rng.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
                rng.Find.Format = false;
                rng.Find.MatchCase = false;
                rng.Find.MatchWholeWord = false;
                rng.Find.MatchWildcards = false;
                rng.Find.Execute();

                if (!rng.Find.Found)
                    break;

                // increment counter
                totalPageBreaks++;

                // do some processing here if you'd like

                // reset the range
                rng.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
            }
```

Comment: What happen if i add blank page or cover page in word document, above code will consider blank page as a page break?